# How can I send data across methods without fields, parameters or return types?

Tags: java

My class is a sensor, it can be on or off, ive been told I need to remove the "on" field as the only fields I can use are the two lists.
How can I remove the "on" field and still make the class function, without changing the sensor interface (so no changing the return types or adding parameters  to the on, off, isOn methods)?

```
    public class AverageSensor implements Sensor {
    private ArrayList<Sensor> sensorList = new ArrayList<Sensor>();
    private List<Integer> readingsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private boolean on = false;

    public void addSensor(Sensor additional) {
        sensorList.add(additional);
        for (Sensor i : sensorList) {
            if ((!i.isOn())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        on = true;
    }

    public List<Integer> readings() {
        return readingsList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOn() {
        if (on) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void on() {
        for (Sensor i : sensorList) {
            i.on();
        }
        on = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void off() {
        for (Sensor i : sensorList) {
            if ((!i.isOn())) {
                on = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        for (Sensor i : sensorList) {
            i.off();
            on = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int measure() {
        int total = 0;
        int average = 0;
        if ((!isOn()) || sensorList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        for (Sensor i : sensorList) {
            total = total + i.measure();
        }
        average = total / sensorList.size();
        readingsList.add(average);
        return average;
    }


}
```

Comment: not. you have to save the state somewhere (fields) or return the values.

Comment: The same way you switch on/off all contained sensors. (Although I would actually question this semantic)

Comment: It looks like your class is a container for sensors, which are meant to either be all on or all off. That being the case, you don't need an `on` boolean. You can determine state by looking at the list of sensors (perhaps with the convention that no sensors = off).

Comment: The on field is redundant, and is a recipe for bugs: if one of the sensors that was on turns off, your AverageSenson isOn() method will keep returning hat you stored previously in the field. Change it so that it iterates through all the sensors every time it's called and returns the value.

Comment: To explain with a simple example: if you design a Circle class, there is no need for a field radius and another field diameter. The latter is always the double of the former. So having two fields only makes it possible to have a buggy circle where the diameter is not the double of the radius. So the `getDiameter()` method should be `return radius * 2`. Same here: your global `on`status should be computed from the `on`status of each of the sensors. All your methods will become much simpler, too.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!